# Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{8^{n}}= \sqrt{2}$ using $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{8^{n}}= \sqrt{2}$ using $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$

For the past 2 days I've tried to prove this but with no results.
I've done some research but with no results.
Any ideas how can I finally solve this?

Comment: this might be relaed to the [Catalan Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)

Comment: @imranfat well,after I've confirmed that this series converges I've tried to solve it representing the series like an integral,but I couldn't find the proper solution..Then I've tried to manipulate the series to get a binomial expression but once again with no result.

Comment: @cactus314 I doubt so because this is an test example from Discrete Math at my Faculty and we haven't learned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Us the extended binomial theorem to show that:

$$(1-x)^{-1/2} = 1 +\frac{1}{1!}\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2!}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{3!}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{5}{2}x^3\dots$$

And then prove (by induction or just directly) that:

$$\frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{5}{2}...\frac{2n-1}{2} = \frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}$$

This means that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$$

Then substitute $4x$ for $x$ and you get a power series for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$ and then use $x=1/8$.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you,but could you please explain me how did you prove this equation?
$\frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{5}{2}...\frac{2n-1}{2} = \frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}$

Comment: @DraganZrilić Notice that $$y=2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\ldots\cdot2n=2^n(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot n)=2^nn!$$If $z=1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)$, what can you conclude about $y\cdot z=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n)$

Comment: :D [I figured this out](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022631/sum-of-the-given-series/2022712#2022712) a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use [Newton's generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) for negative exponent.